# why I need 'new' for array parameter?

Tags: java

```
int add(int[] scores){ ... }
-------------------------------
int result = add({1,2,3});  //wrong
int result = add(new int[] {1,2,3});  //correct
```

I know I have to code like this but
why we must put 'new int[]' for parameter??

Comment: You just do, this is how the language is specified. There's no deeper reason.

Comment: `long[] l = {1, 2, 3};` is valid as well, so how would your method determine it doesn't get passed a `long[]`? You have to specify the type...

Comment: *FYI:* If you declared the method to use varargs, you wouldn't need to. Method declaration: `int add(int.. scores)`. Call syntax: `add(1,2,3)`. Notice the lack of `{ }` in the call syntax. Method otherwise works like before, i.e. `scores` is type `int[]`.

Answer (score 3):

The array initializer syntax (`{1, 2, 3}`) can only be used [in certain circumstances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a field declaration (§8.3, §9.3) or local variable declaration (§14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10.1), to create an array and provide some initial values.

In other circumstances, you would need to use an array creation expression (e.g. `new int[] {1, 2, 3}`).

This is just how the language is specified. It could be different, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out, the array initialize can only be used in variable declarations.

You might want to use varargs in you example like that:

```
int add(int... scores){ ... }
```

You can call it in two ways:

```
int result = add(1,2,3); 
int result = add(new int[] {1,2,3});
```

Comment: Pointed out by who?

Comment: By @Andy Turner in the other answer

Comment: Ok. I thought you may have meant [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721393/why-i-need-new-for-array-parameter/63722072?noredirect=1#comment112680528_63721393)